# Does $f_n(x) = (x + 1/n)^2$ uniformly converge

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I have it converging pointwise to $x^2$. Using a choice of $x = n$, I'm showing that the limit as $n$ tends to infinity of the supremum$(|f_n - f|) \ge 2$. Which since it isn't zero shows it doesn't uniformly diverge. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes if you domain contains $\Bbb N.$ and if by "it doesn't uniformly diverge" you meant "it doesn't uniformly converge".

Comment: domain is the reals, sorry forgot to mention. Thank you Anne

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9201/proposal-discourage-questions-that-are-nothing-besides-a-problem-statement), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please edit the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) will help you recognize and resolve the issues.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that we have some sequence of functions $f_n$ converges to $f$ if it fulfills the following definition (equivalent to convergence under the supremum metric):

$$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N} \text{ s.t. } \forall x \in D \text{ and } \forall n \geq N, |f_{n}(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon$$

Let us for this sake consider $|f_{n}(x) - f(x)|$. We can expand it to equal $|\frac{1}{n^2} + \frac{2x}{n}|$. There is something immediately concerning here which hints that the sequence may not uniformly converge: we have an $x$ in the numerator which is seemingly uncontrollable. For this sake, we may try our luck showing it doesn't uniformly converge by use of the negation of the definition.

$$\exists \epsilon > 0 \text{ s.t } \forall N \in \mathbb{N}, \exists x \in D \text{ s.t. } \exists n \geq N \text{ s.t. } |f_{n}(x) - f(x)| \geq \epsilon$$

We will consider $\epsilon = 1$, and for this sake let $N \in \mathbb{N}$. We turn now to the same $|\frac{1}{n^2} + \frac{2x}{n}|$. As we are just looking for some $x$, we may as well relegate our attention to $x \geq 0$, in which case we can drop the absolute value.

We are just then looking for some value of $x, n \geq N$ s.t. $\frac{1}{n^2} + \frac{2x}{n} \geq 1$. To simplify, say $n = N$ and remark the inequality $\frac{1}{N^2} + \frac{2x}{N} \geq \frac{2x}{N}$ here. To get $\frac{2x}{N} \geq 1$, then, we just choose $x \geq \frac{N}{2}$. It is therefore evident the sequence does not uniformly converge, as we find values of $x$ for which $f_n$ explodes past the "$\epsilon$-ribbon" (as I like to call it) of $x^2$.